# Estimate a Nonlinear Constraint as a Linear Constraint that is compatible with a MIQP problem

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am new to optimization and currently writing a Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming problem with linear constraints. However, I have encountered a nonlinear constraint (two or more different variables multiplied to each other) which I would like to model as a linear constraint instead. [Mccormick Envelope](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes)  is one technique that has been used, but I think it can only be used for an LP problem instead of a QP. (Please let me know if I am incorrect)

I wanted to know if there is a method that can convert nonlinear constraints into linear constraints while being compatible with an MIQP problem.

Comment: Try this on or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not sure why you are saying that Mccormick relaxations can be used only in LPs. Note that Gurobi can handle non-convex quadratic terms in the constraints directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming options available in Python such as `pyomo` and `gekko` with solvers such as `BONMIN` and `APOPT`. Here is a simple MINLP problem solved in `gekko`:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # create GEKKO model
x1 = m.Var(integer=True,lb=-5,ub=10) 
# create Special Ordered Set variable
x2 = m.sos1([0.5, 1.15, 2.6, 5.2])
# add nonlinear equation
x3 = m.Var()
m.Equation((x3+x2)**2==m.tanh(x1))
m.Minimize(4*x1**2-4*x2*x1**2+x2**2+x1**2-x1+x3)
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver
m.solve()
for x in [x1,x2,x3]:
    print(x.value[0])
```

The solver creates successive QP solutions to find a search direction as a Sequential Quadratic Programming solver with Branch and Bound for the integer variables.

```
 Number of state variables:              7
 Number of total equations: -            3
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              4
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I: 0 Tm: 0.00 NLPi: 12 Dpth: 0 Lvs: 0 Obj: -1.57E+03 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.489999999466818E-002 sec
 Objective      :   -1569.15999999794     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
10.0
5.2
-6.1999999979
```

If you require that the problem is reformulated as an MIQP problem, another approach is to move all variables to one side of the equation and take the first three terms of a Taylor series expansion to get a quadratic approximation or first two terms for a linear approximation of the constraint. This approximation is only valid near the point of linearization.